# In a Venn diagram with three sets $A, B \text{ and } C,$ how can we denote the region that belong only to $A?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a three set Venn diagram, is there a short way to denote the region 
$(A \cup B \cup C) - ( B \cup C)$ ?

Comment: the region you've specified in the title is not the same as the one in the text.

Comment: at least in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for any setup of the diagram $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$ is about the shortest way you could denote the one in the title.  this is literally the elements in (the elements in A that are not in B) that are not in C.

Answer (score 3):

I would write $A \setminus (B \cup C)$.

Comment: probably depends on the setup of the venn diagram if this would work.

Comment: I added an answer of my own, but I prefer this myself!

Comment: $\huge {\huge {O}\!\!O\!\!O}$  for example if the first is B the second is A and the third is C you get the elements of A that are not part of the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Also: $$A\cap B^\prime\cap C^\prime$$ meaning the region that **is** $A$, is **not** $B$ and is **not** $C$.

(As I understand it, Americans might prefer the superscript ${ }^c$ for the complement of a set, while Europeans tend to use this to indicate the radian unit of measure if necessary, which by contrast Americans might represent with ${ }^r$!)